# How can I save the thread results in a Database

Tags: android, database, multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe5

Work on a project and I want to save the images I downloadin a blob field. I use idHTTP with success but UI freezes.

I create a procedure to download images from URL using ImageLoader method ([Image Loader page](http://www.pockhero.com/imageloader-for-firemonkey-timage-component/)). Everything is OK with the images but I cannot save them in the specific field in DB.

How can I do it?

Here is my code :

```
procedure TForm1.LoadImages;
var
  i: integer;
  IMLO: TImageLoader;
  IM: TImage;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  imgAddress: string;

begin
  Table1.First;
   for i := 0 to Table1.RecordCount-1 do
     begin
       imgAddress := Table1.FieldByName('URL').AsString;
       Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
       IM:= TImage.Create(self);
       IM.Name := 'IM'+inttostr(i);
       IM.Parent := HorzScrollBox1;
       IM.Position.X := i * 320;
       IM.Align:= TAlignLayout.alLeft;
       IM.Width := 300;
       IMLO.LoadImage(IM, imgAddress);
 {      Table1.Edit;
       TBlobField(Table1.FieldByName('image')).LoadFromStream(Stream);
       Table1.Post; 
       Stream.Free;  }
       Table1.Next;
     end;
end;
```

The code works perfectly if I want just to show images. How can I use stream to save them?

Comment: What does this have to do with the `android` tag?

Comment: And I did not see any multithread related source ...

Comment: Why aren't you Free()ing IM?

Comment: it's procedure in an Android program.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Except for the fact that you are not freeing stuff that you `create` in the loop. Other than that your code follows the spec: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TBlobField.LoadFromStream  Do you get an error?

Comment: I Free IM before Table.Next and I get errors

Comment: I feel that the code save the images but empty (before they download).

Comment: @Rynak, no silly, do you get an error when putting the data in the blob field? Also never say `I get errors`: specify the exact text of the error.

Comment: I have no error with the BLOB field is just empty. and SORRY the error was from another procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**
The problem is that the `TImageLoader.LoadImage` loads the data from the net asynchronously.
Because of that the data is not yet available at the time when you're loading the data.

**Simple solution**
In order to stop TImageLoader from doing that you can add an extra method to it and call that one instead.
The other problem is that you are loading the Blob with the `Stream` data, but you never load the stream with anything.
Luckily you don't need the stream.

```
function TImageLoader.LoadImageNow(const AImage: TImage; const AImageURL: string): boolean;
const
  success = true;
  failure = false;
var
  MS : TMemoryStream;
  Image: TImage;
begin
  Result:= success;
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Image:= TImage.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.get(AImageURL,MS);
    Ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);       
    Image.LoadFromStream(MS);
    AImage.Picture.Assign(Image);   
  except
    Result:= failure;
  end;
  FreeAndNil(Image);
  FreeAndNil(MS);
end;
```

Now the loader will only return when the image is loaded. 
This also explains why you get an exception upon freeing `IM`.
You're freeing IM, but the loader is still using it in the background.
That's the problem with using multi-threaded applications, you need to keep track of what the other threads are doing.

The code for your loop will now look like this:

```
procedure TForm1.LoadImages;
var
  i: integer;
  IMLO: TImageLoader;
  IM: TImage;
  imgAddress: string;
  FieldImage: TGraphicField;
  FieldUrl: TField;
begin
  FieldImage:= TGraphicField(Table1.FieldByName('image'));
  FieldUrl:= Table1.FieldByName('URL');

  Table1.First;
  for i := 0 to Table1.RecordCount-1 do try
    imgAddress := FieldUrl.AsString;
    IM:= TImage.Create(self);
    IM.Name := 'IM'+inttostr(i);
    IM.Parent := HorzScrollBox1;
    IM.Position.X := i * 320;
    IM.Align:= TAlignLayout.alLeft;
    IM.Width := 300;
    if IMLO.LoadImageNow(IM, imgAddress) then begin
      Table1.Edit;
      FieldImage.Assign(IM.Picture);
      Table1.Post; 
    end; {if}
  finally  
    IM.Free;
    Stream.Free;  
    Table1.Next;
  end; {for .. try}
end;
```

Because `FieldByName` is slow it is best to pull it out of a loop (it probably will not matter because of the slowness of `LoadImageNow`).

See: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TBlobField.Assign
And: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/HTTP_Get_%28Delphi%29

**Other option**
Add an event to the thread that you can hook into every time a image finishes loading.
In the event handler you can then display the image and put it into the database.
In fact the async loader may already have an option for this, but I do not know that codebase well enough to answer that question.